# Using awk to get nth field from a particular line

Tags: bash, awk, centos

I have written a bash script that is supposed to get version number of ghostscript. The code looks like this:

```
local str=$(gs -v)
local gs_version=''
if [ -n "$str" ] ; then
  gs_version=`awk -F'|' 'Ghostscript/ {version=$3; print version}' $str`
fi
echo " version: $gs_version"
```

The result of gs -v is:

```
GPL Ghostscript 8.70 (2009-07-31)
Copyright (C) 2009 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
```

The script is looking for the word Ghostscript and is trying to extract the third word which is 8.70. That is my objective.

I am not an awk expert, but when I run this code I get the following error:

```
awk: Ghostscript/ {version=$3; print version}
awk:              ^ syntax error
```

I guess I must be going blind as I don't see what is wrong. I thought I had this working on Ubuntu but when I try it on CentOS 6 this is what I get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say:

```
awk '/Ghostscript/{print $3}' inputfile
```

to get the third field from the line containing Ghostscript.

When you say:

```
gs_version=`awk -F'|' 'Ghostscript/ {version=$3; print version}' $str`
```

there is:

- a missing `/` before Ghostscript
- moreover, since you want `awk` to read from a string you need to make use of herestring.
- fields are delimited by whitespace by default so you don't need to supply one (not sure why you used `|`, though)

```
gs_version=$(awk '/Ghostscript/ {version=$3; print version}' <<< "$str")
```

Although there was simpler ways to get the version information.

Comment: to expand that to your use case, `gs_version=$(gs -v | awk -F'|' '/Ghostscript/ {print $3}')`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error and for providing a simpler way to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you can use `grep -P` to grab that version string:

```
gs -v | grep -oP '(?<=Ghostscript )\S+'
8.70
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I will remember that the next time I need to do this.